# genStats.py file does not work in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, sumo

I'm working with SUMO, I need to use genStats.py for statistic data but I'm getting some errors.

My code;

```html
import sys
import random
from subprocess import call

tripInfoFile = "my_intersection.trips.xml"
statsFile = "my_intersection.stats.xml"     # statistics file results (output)

retcode = call(["python","networkStatistics.py","-t", tripInfoFile,"-o", statsFile])
```

Error;
[THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7FKz.jpg)

**I can't understand this error, I'm using Python 2.7.16 version because this code does not work in new versions.**

Comment: This is just a starter for another script where the error actually happens.

Comment: Are you sure that your input file is not empty?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the file is not empty

Comment: And is the file properly finished, so does it end with a `</tripinfos>` element?

Comment: Thanks, I fix it. Now running correctly.